# Django 1.11 Admin TypeError

Tags: django, django-admin

Добрый день! Джанго не дает зайти на страницу админки, просит позиционные аргументы

> TypeError at /admin/login/ get() missing 2 required positional
>   arguments: 'args' and 'kwargs'

Что за беда такая? Раньше на всех приложениях в админку заходил без проблем. В созданные приложения по урлам ходит нормально. urls.py следующий:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    ]
```

Comment: UPD:
Если запускать на порте 8001, а не на 8000, то все нормально. С чем такое может быть связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в куки. После чистки браузера все стало работать хорошо.